# Pass dir output as argument to another command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vlc

I want to join .mp4 videos using VLC. The [following command](https://superuser.com/questions/736261/joining-videos-using-the-command-line) works nicely when entered into a Windows command prompt:

```
vlc input_1.mp4 input_2.mp4 --sout "#gather:std{access=file,dst=output.mp4}" --sout-keep
```

I would like to generalize this incantation so that I don't have to adjust the list of input files manually. I want all mp4 files in the current directory, in alphabetical order. Ideally something like this:

```
files = dir *.mp4 -b -o:n
vlc %files% --sout "#gather:std{access=file,dst=output.mp4}" --sout-keep
```

The first line obviously does not work like that. I played around with the command a bit, but things quickly become awkward when file names contain spaces or (gasp!) exclamation points. I also tried PowerShell (both `Start-Process` and `&`), but due to lack of experience could not figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using powershell to generate that cmd command try below options

executing from powershell:

```
cmd /c "vlc $((dir *.mp4).Name -join ' ') --sout ""#gather:std{access=file,dst=output.mp4}"" --sout-keep"
```

executing from cmd:

```
powershell -c "echo ""vlc $((dir *.mp4).Name -join ' ') --sout ""#gather:std{access=file,dst=output.mp4}"" --sout-keep""" | cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

your 2nd example looks like a mixture of invalid batch and invalid powershell code.

In a batch file this might do :
(as long as the length of the files string doesn't exceed max cmd line length)

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "files="
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /ON *.mp4') Do Set "files=!files! "%%A""
vlc %files% --sout "#gather:std{access=file,dst=output.mp4}" --sout-keep
```